# Multiple value Chi Squared test in SPSS

Tags: spss, chi-squared-test

I am currently doing a study into factors that affect mortality in a particular type of bacterial infection.

I would like to compare certain patient characteristics. One of which is the specialty that the patient is under. I currently have a variable in SPSS that has three values according to the three specialties I have grouped my patients in: 'Haematological', 'surgical' or 'other'. I would like to see if there is any statistical significance between each of these specialties and whether the patient survived or died during their hospital stay.

I assume because I am dealing with categorical data I have to do a Chi Square test, however I would like to look at whether each specialty is significant individually not just if there is any significant relationship between 'specialties' and death. Is there any way of getting SPSS to do this, or do I need to break them up individually?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do chi-square, you can do logistic regression with "survival" as the dependent variable and "specialty" as the independent variable. This will also allow you to have covariates, which is probably necessary.